# Returning value of a function that called with __call

Tags: php, oop

I'm thinking, this is a weird behaviour but if it's not, it's surely deficient feature of PHP or please tell me how can I do.

These are my codes:

child.php

```
class child extends father {
    public $name = "John Borned";

    public function __construct( $name ) {
        parent::__construct( $name );
    }

    public function __call($function, $params){
        $this->surname = "child call surname";
        parent::__call($function, $params);
        call_user_func_array( array( $this, $function ),$params );

    }

    protected function nameIt( $name ) {
        $this->name = $name;
        return $this->surname;
    }
}
```

father.php

```
class father {

    public $name;
    public $surname = "Roe";

    public function __construct( $name ) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function __call($function,$params) {
        $this->surname = "father call surname";
    }
}
```

and dummy.php

```
include("father.php");
include("child.php");

$c = new child( "Jane" );
$n = $c->nameIt( "Jane" );

var_dump( $n );
```

This is the problem: Echoing `$this->surname` in nameIt function works and the value is "father call surname". That's ok. But `var_dump( $n );` says `NULL` if nameIt function try to return `$this->surname`. Why? Why I can not return any value from `protected function nameIt` ? How can that function return a value?

PS: These classes and their usage are just mimesis of my real intent. So please don't say you're verbose.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `$n = $c->nameIt( "Jane" );` you are calling `child::__call` that don't return anything. I think you should write

```
return call_user_func_array( array( $this, $function ),$params );
```

in your `child::__call` method

**Addition**

following to [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call)  there is no any differences between `__call` and normal methods except it is a magic method that called instead of private, protected or nonexistent methods of a class.

So in your case you can read your code

```
$n = $c->nameIt( "Jane" );
```

as

```
$n = $c->__call('nameIt', 'Jane' );
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. Surprisingly. But I need more explanation to be clear how it works.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that's just about visibility:

```
class A
{
    protected function echo() 
    {
        echo "PROTECTED";
    }
    
    public function __call($function, $params)
    {
        echo "Magic Method";
    }
} 
$a = new A();
$a->echo();
```

prints "Magic Method",
whereas:

```
class A
{
    public function echo() 
    {
        echo "PROTECTED";
    }
    
    public function __call($function, $params)
    {
        echo "Magic Method";
    }
} 
$a = new A();
$a->echo();
```

prints "PROTECTED"